# How to change the width of columns using angular-scrollable-table

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angular-scrollable-table because it has fixed-headers. I need the table to flow horizontal with the column headers in full view. I have tried changing the css but I can't get it to work. 
plunkr
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/24OJVHQhjRhqRj8akvQX?p=preview)

```
   <scrollable-table watch="jobArray">
 <div class="table-responsive" >
<table class=" table table-bordred table-striped table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">Job Number</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">Name</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">Customer</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">PM</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">Superintendent</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">Tax Exempt</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">Cert Payroll</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">Status</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">Contract</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">Total CO</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">Revised Contract</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">Job Cost</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">Budget</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">Remaining Budget</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">Profit</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">%</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">Total Billed</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">Balance To Bill</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">Paid to Date</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">Balance Due</th>
    <th style="font-weight: bold;">Contract Date</th>


  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="job in jobArray" class="pointer">
      <td ng-click="editJobModal(job)">{{job.JobNumber}}</td>
      <td>{{job.JobName}}</td>
      <td>{{job.Customers[0].CustomerName}}</td>
      <td>{{job.TESPM}}</td>
      <td>{{job.TESSuperintendent}}</td>
      <td>{{job.TaxExempt}}</td>
      <td>{{job.CertPayroll}}</td>
      <td>{{job.Status}}</td>
      <td>${{job.OriginalContract | number : fractionSize}}</td>
      <td>${{job.TotalCO | number : fractionSize}}</td>
      <td>${{job.RevisedContract | number : fractionSize}}</td>
      <td>${{job.JobCost | number : fractionSize}}</td>
      <td>${{job.Budget | number : fractionSize}}</td>
      <td>${{job.RemainingBudget | number : fractionSize}}</td>
      <td>${{job.Profit | number : fractionSize}}</td>
      <td>{{job.Percentage}}%</td>
      <td>${{job.TotalBilled | number : fractionSize}}</td>
      <td>${{job.BalanceToBill | number : fractionSize}}</td>
      <td>${{job.PaidToDate | number : fractionSize}}</td>
      <td>${{job.BalanceDue | number : fractionSize}}</td>
      <td>{{job.ContractDate | date : date : shortDate}}</td>


    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
 </scrollable-table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make two changes. First embed all the content inside each `th`/`td` inside a div and then use css to set the width of both the `th`/`td` as well as the `div` inside it. In my example I set them all to 200px but you should use css classes to set them tow whatever you really need.

Then you need to modify angular-scrollable-table to remove everything it does related to column resizing. Basically search for width and delete everything.

This updated plnkr works and includes the modified angular-scrollable-table. See changes in angular-scrollable-table.min.js, the html, and the css (note the min.js is not min anymore).

http://plnkr.co/edit/2iGEEGqoMB6aFnsQgsUz?p=preview

Comment: The issue now is the fixed headers and sorting. they no longer work?

Comment: @user3919120, yeah, that happens when you delete code ;) It's still scrollable. If you want to keep other functionality you'll need to dive deeper into how scrollable list works to change it differently from how I've recommended. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: @user3919120, great! do you mind updating the plnkr so if anyone else has the same question they can benefit from the complete answer?